# массив структур через vector.выдает ошибку. vector iterator not incrementable

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct treem 
{
char node[5];
char parent[5];
int number;
};

vector <treem> CreateAtree()
{
char value[5];
char parn[5];
int num;

vector<treem> tree;
treem g;


printf("Input the name of the root\n");
scanf("%s",&value);
printf("Input the value of node\n");
scanf("%d", &num);

tree.push_back(g);
strcpy(tree.at(0).parent,"NO");
strcpy(tree.at(0).node, value);
tree.at(0).number = num;
int i = 1;
int flag = 0;

while (num != 0 && parn[0] != '0')
{
    printf("Input the name of node\n");
    scanf("%s",&value);
    printf("Input the parent of node\n");
    scanf("%s",&parn);
    printf("Input the value of node\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);


    for (vector<treem>::iterator it = tree.begin(); it != tree.end(); it++)
    {
        if (strcmp(parn, it->node) == 0)
            flag = 1;
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            tree.push_back(g);
            strcpy(tree.at(i).parent, parn);
            strcpy(tree.at(i).node, value);
            tree.at(i).number = num;
            i++;
            flag = 0;
        }
        else
            printf("There is not such parent,please try again\n");
    }

}
return tree;
}

int main()
{
vector<treem> tree = CreateAtree();

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Делаю что-то вроде дерева. Создаю корень тогда когда добавляю новую вершину
и указываю корень(у меня там проверка идет) выбивает сообщение vector iterator not incrementable . С vector работаю впервые поэтому прошу совета как исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Данный цикл не имеет смысла, так как внутри цикла добавляются элементы в вектор в виду чего итераторы становятся не валидными, так как вектор может переопределять память, чтобы вместить новые элементы.

```
for (vector<treem>::iterator it = tree.begin(); it != tree.end(); it++)
{
    if (strcmp(parn, it->node) == 0)
        flag = 1;
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        tree.push_back(g);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Что вам надо - это использовать алгоритм `std::find_if` или `std::any_of` вместо цикла, и, если родительский элемент найден, то добавлять новый элемент в вектор, после чего использовать функцию-член класса `back` для изменения значений данного добавленного элемента.

К тому же у вас в дереве нет связи между узлами дерева.

Ниже показано, как можно переписать ваш код, чтобы по крайней мере он работал.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>

const size_t N = 5;

struct treem
{
    char node[N];
    char parent[N];
    int number;
};

std::vector<treem> CreateAtree()
{
    std::vector<treem> tree;
    treem node;

    std::cout << "Input the name of the root: ";
    std::cin.getline(node.node, N);

    std::cout << "Input the value of node: ";
    std::cin >> node.number;

    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::strcpy(node.parent, "NO");

    tree.push_back(node);

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Input the parent of the next node: ";

        if ( !std::cin.getline(node.parent, N) || node.parent[0] == '\0') break;

        if (std::any_of(tree.begin(), tree.end(),
            [&](const treem &t)
        {
            return std::strcmp(t.node, node.parent) == 0;
        }))
        {
            std::cout << "Input the name of the next node: ";
            std::cin.getline(node.node, N);

            std::cout << "Input the value of the next node: ";
            std::cin >> node.number;

            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            tree.push_back(node);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "There is no such parent,please try again\n";
        }

    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return tree;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<treem> tree = CreateAtree();

    for (const treem &node : tree)
    {
        std::cout << "parent: " << node.parent
            << ", name: " << node.node
            << ", value: " << node.number
            << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Диалог с программой может выглядеть следующим образом

```
Input the name of the root: A
Input the value of node: 0
Input the parent of the next node: A
Input the name of the next node: B
Input the value of the next node: 1
Input the parent of the next node: A
Input the name of the next node: C
Input the value of the next node: 2
Input the parent of the next node: B
Input the name of the next node: D
Input the value of the next node: 3
Input the parent of the next node:

parent: NO, name: A, value: 0
parent: A, name: B, value: 1
parent: A, name: C, value: 2
parent: B, name: D, value: 3
```

Comment: что надо изменить чтобы этот код заработал так как я хочу, ради интереса,хочу чтобы этот код заработал.

Comment: @toshka-pitoshka Надо переписать код с учетом моего ответа.